# Can Principal Component Analysis be applied on 2D geometry with X and Y nodes in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, 2d, pca, dimensionality-reduction

**Aim of the task:** I have sets of coordinates (X and Y) coordinates of the geometry and I want to make my geometry aligned. The coordinate and respective geometry is shown in the picture.

```
X1_coordinate = [0.0, 0.87, 1.37, 1.87, 2.73, 3.6, 4.46, 4.96, 5.46, 4.6, 3.73, 2.87, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 2.37, 3.23, 4.1]
Y1_coordinate = [0.0, 0.5, -0.37, -1.23, -0.73, -0.23, 0.27, -0.6, -1.46, -1.96, -2.46, -2.96, -3.46, -2.6, -1.73, -0.87, -2.1, -1.6, -1.1]
```

[image]

**Question:** Can I apply Principal Component Analysis on 2D geometries to make it aligned such that its principal axis will be parallel to the reference axis (X and Y)?

**Expected output:** I want my geometry like this. This is just an example. I want my geometry in such as way that, principal axis of geometry lies on the reference axis or be parallel to reference axis.

[image]

**What I tried:** I tried below code to implement PCA and to obtain the geometry aligned.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
plt.style.use('ggplot')
# Load the data
# iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = X1_coordinate
y = Y1_coordinate
# Z-score the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
# The PCA model
pca = PCA(n_components=2) # estimate only 2 PCs
X_new = pca.fit_transform(X) # project the original data into the PCA space
```

However, after running the code, I got error as mentioned below.

[image]

Kindly let me know what should I do to make my geometry aligned. Looking forward to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can apply PCA to this task.

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

circle_pts = sklearn.datasets.make_circles() #get two circles with labels
circle_pts = circle_pts[0][circle_pts[1]==0] #leave only one circle

ang = 63/180*np.pi #radians of rotation
R = np.array([[np.cos(ang), -np.sin(ang)], [np.sin(ang), np.cos(ang)]])

ellipse_pts = circle_pts
ellipse_pts[:,0] *= 4.5
ellipse_rot_pts = ellipse_pts @ R.T

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(ellipse_rot_pts[:,0], ellipse_rot_pts[:,1])
plt.axis("equal")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


scaler = StandardScaler(with_std=False)
scaler.fit(ellipse_rot_pts)
X = scaler.transform(ellipse_rot_pts)
pca = PCA(n_components=2) # estimate only 2 PCs
X_new = pca.fit_transform(X) # project the original data into the PCA space


plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])

singular_values = pca.singular_values_
plt.plot([0, singular_values[0]*pca.components_[0,0]], [0, singular_values[0]*pca.components_[0,1]])
plt.plot([0, singular_values[1]*pca.components_[1,0]], [0, singular_values[1]*pca.components_[1,1]])

plt.axis("equal")
plt.show() 


plt.figure()
plt.title("Aligned with axis figure")
plt.scatter(X_new[:,0],X_new[:,1])
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

But the problem is that not every geometry is appropriate for this. ellipse has two main axis of symmetry. Your figure for example doesn't. So principal components that are been seeking via maximum variance in data doesn't correspond with your example(expected output) axis alignement.

For example your set of points correspond to this variant of components alignment:
[Your geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdnqb.jpg)

And for a modificated little more symmetric object.
[A little more symmetrical figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnX8W.jpg)

Hope i helped

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what I understood from your answer is: PCA can only be applied to geometries which is symmetric. Right?

Comment: What are other possibilties to align (or make parallel) the principal axis of geometry to reference axis X or Y? How can I find the principal axis of such geometries?

Comment: @Urvesh In short, for this task PCA can be applied(and solve) not only for symmetric geometries(imagine cross from the flag of Denmark for example - is isn't symmetric for both axis). So you should understand statistical rules which is used to find principal vectors.

Comment: @Urvesh I don't have exact solution for you example. But recommend you to develop rule to find axis of geometry(as you see them - and not as PCA count them) and then rotate basis